# In what way is Google's index stored?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

What is the architecture used to store the index in the DB by Google and how many tables does Google maintain for indexing?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article at High Scalability:
http://highscalability.com/google-architecture

There is also a similar question posted here:
[How can Google be so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132359/how-can-google-be-so-fast)