# Learning about MySql for large database/tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a new site of mine for a couple of days now which will be retrieving almost all of its most used content from a MySql database. Seeming as the Database and website is still under development the tables are really small at the moment and speed is of no concern yet.

But you know what they say, a little bit of hard work now saves you a headache later on.
Now I'm only 17, the only database I've ever been taught was through Microsoft Access, and we were practically given the database completed - we learned up to 3NF, but that was about it.

I remember reading once when I was looking to pull data (randomly) out of a database how large databases were taking several seconds/minutes to complete a single query, so this just got me thinking. In a fraction of a second I can submit a search to google, google processes the query and returns the result, and then my browser renders it - all done in the blink of an eye. And google has billions of records to search through. And they're also doing this for millions of users simultaneously.

I'm thinking, how do they do it? I know that they have huge data centers, but still.

I realize that it probably comes down to the design of the database, how it's been optimized, and obviously the configuration. And I guess that's my question really. Could someone please tell me how to design high performance databases for millions/billions of rows (yes, I'm being optimistic), and possibly point me towards some good reading material to help me learn further?

Also, all my queries are done via PHP, if that's at all relevant to any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the good news... MySQL scales well (depending on the hardware) to at least hundreds of millions of rows.

Once you get to a certain point, a single database server will have trouble managing the load.  That's when you get into the realm of [partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) or [sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)... spreading the load across multiple database servers using any one of a number of different schemes (e.g. putting unrelated tables on different servers, spreading a single table across multiple servers e.g. by using the ID or date range as a partitioning key).

SQL does shard, but is not fundamentally designed to shard well.  There's a whole category of storage alternatives collectively referred to as [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) that are designed to solve that very problem ([MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) are a few).

When you use SQL at very large scale, you run into any number of issues such as making data model changes across a DB server farm, trouble keeping up with data backups, etc.  That's a very complex topic, and people that solve it well are rare.  For a glimpse at the issues, have a look at http://gigaom.com/cloud/facebook-trapped-in-mysql-fate-worse-than-death/

When selecting a database platform for a specific project, benchmark the solution early and often to understand whether or not it will meet the performance requirements that you envision.  Having a framework to do that will help you learn about scalability, and will help you decide whether to invest effort in improving the data storage part of your solution, and will help you know where best to invest your time.

Comment: I have to say that your facebook link here really caught my eye; one of the things I was thinking for this potential site is a wall similar to facebook's, so being able to read about their problems is a great insight to the idea. I'll definately be looking into NewSql.

Answer (score 1):

The blog http://highscalability.com/ has some good articles and pointers to how companies handle large problems.

Specifically related to MySQL, you can Google for craigslist.org's use of MySQL.

http://www.slideshare.net/jzawodn/mysql-and-search-at-craigslist

Comment: Great thanks, I'll be sure to re-visit these sites when it's not 3am so I can soak up the information properly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Sphinx server.

http://sphinxsearch.com/

Craigslist uses that for their search engine. Basically, you give it a source and it indexes whatever you want (mysql database/table, text files, etc.). If it works for craigslist, it should work for you.

Comment: Okay cheers, the page is bookmarked and I'll probably read it tonight, when I'll be able to get on the computer for a decent amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell how to design databases. It comes after much reading and many hour working on them. A good design is product of many many years doing them though. As you've only seen Access you got no knowledge of databases. Search through Amazon.com and you'll get tons of titles. For someone that's starting, anyone will do it.

I mean no disrespect. I've been there and I'm also tutor of some people learning programming/database design. I do know that there's no silver bullet or shortcuts for the work you have ahead.

If you intend to work with high performance database, you should have something in mind. The design of them in per application. A good design depends on learning more and more how the app's users interact with the system, the usage patterns, etc. The things you'll learn from books will give you options, using them will depend heavily on the scenario.

Good luck!

Comment: I've been programming for a good 6 or 7 years now, admittedly not in "real" languages until the last year or so. But this is my first serious encounter with databases - so I'm looking for all the reading material I can find so I make less mistakes out in the real world! :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't all come down to the design of the database, though that is indeed a big part of it. The guys who made Google are geniouses, and if I'm not completely wrong about Google you won't be able to find out exactly how they do what they do. Also, I know that years back they had more than 10,000 computers processing queries, and today they probably have many more. I also suspect them for caching most of the recent/popular keywords. And all the websites have been indexed and analyzed using an unknown algorithm which will make sure the computers don't have to look through all the words on every page.
In fact, Google crawls the entire internet around every 14 days, so when you do a search you do *not* search the entire internet. Your search gets broken down into keywords and then these keywords are used to narrow the number of relevant pages - and I'm pretty sure all pages have already been analyzed for important and/or relevant keywords before you even thought of visiting google.com.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132359/how-can-google-be-so-fast).

Comment: Google in fact does not use expensive hardware, they opted to use a large amount of inexpensive computers with built in software reliability and redundancy.

See: http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/06/11/JeffDeanOnGoogleInfrastructure.aspx

Comment: @xordon Oh well, I guess I was wrong about that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ah yes, I've enjoyed reading about google's servers, they try and balance out the cost, power and performance to find the best overall computer if I remember correctly :)
But that's very interesting that whole "14 days" part.